# Adding additional validation based on reactiveVars to Jquery Validate (Meteor.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, meteor

I have a form, with some regular old inputs, and then some buttons I want a user to click (controlled with reactiveVars).  I only want the form to submit and create a db instance if the form is validated, as well as at least one of the button variables is clicked "true".  However, the way I have it set up now, I realize that 'submit form' won't be called if the inputs are not filled out correctly.

Event handler:

```
Template.inquiry.events({
    'submit form': function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = template.$('#request-form');

        if(Template.instance().report.get() == true || Template.instance().consult.get() == true || Template.instance().contract.get() == true) {

            if ($form.valid()) {

                var name = event.target.name.value;
                var email = event.target.email.value;
 }
        else {
            $('#no-choice-error').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    }
});
```

Jquery validation:

```
emplate.inquiry.onRendered(function(){
    $('#request-form').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 255
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 255
            }
    });
});
```

Pretty much the use case that never gets called is:

```
$('#no-choice-error').removeClass('hidden');
```

How do I make sure this gets called?  Or better yet, integrate the         `if(Template.instance().report.get() == true || Template.instance().consult.get() == true || Template.instance().contract.get() == true)`  rule within the validation with Jquery for the other inputs.

Comment: My suggestion, go with aldeed:autoform. This package will solve most of your problems

Comment: Is there another way?  It seems that this should be a simple thing and the rest of it works fine already without additional packages.

Comment: for instance, using jQuery.validator.addMethod

Comment: An example would be great...